# Remove lines with duplicate patterns in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have a semicolon-seperated text file representing a data table. I want to remove all lines where "columns" 2 and 4 are identical.

Example for source:

```
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
Some;Foo;Text;Foo;;;;
This;line;shall;remain;;;;
;Bar;;Bar;;;;;
```

should result in

```
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
This;line;shall;remain;;;;
```

because the values for the "columns" 2 and 4 ("B" and "D") are equal in the first line ("Foo") and in the last one ("Bar"), but not in the middle one ("line" and "remain").

Each "cell" may contain an arbitrary number of arbitrary characters, except a semicolon.

I am sure the `g[lobal]` command can do this, but I am unable to find the correct pattern to match these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vim regex for *"column 2 and 4 are identical"* is this

```
^[^;]*;\([^;]\+\);[^;]*;\1;
```

You should be able to use that with `:g`.

```
^           # start of line
[^;]*       # anything but a semi-colon (column 1)
;           # delimiter
\(          # start group 1
  [^;]\+    #   anything but a semi-colon, at least 1 character (column 2)
\)          # end group 1
;           # delimiter
[^;]*       # anything but a semi-colon (column 3)
;           # delimiter
\1          # same as group 1 (column 4)
;           # delimiter (to prevent partial matches)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this one:

```
awk -F';' '$2 != $4 {print $0}' your_file
```

result:

```
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
This;line;shall;remain;;;;
```